# Infobip ios trouble with library

Tags: ios, infobip

I need to implement `infobip` library `v2.0.0`, but I have a error when add this `[IBPushClient initializePush]` in my app delegate.

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM
>   jsonRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add -ObjC in the Additional Linker Flags, and everything should work fine